# The use of LinkedList<BigInteger>

Tags: c#, linked-list, biginteger

I've been struggling for a while now with an error I can't fix.
I searched the Internet without any success and started wandering if it is possible what I want to accomplish.

I want the create an array with the a huge amount of nodes, so huge that it I need BigInteger.
I founded that `LinkedList` would fit my solution the best, so I started with this code.

```
BigInteger[] numberlist = { 0, 1 };
LinkedList<BigInteger> number = new LinkedList<BigInteger>(numberlist);
for(c = 2; c <= b; c++) 
{
    numberlist [b] = 1;                  /* flag numbers to 1 */
}
```

The meaning of this is to set all nodes in the linkedlist to active (1).
The vars c and b are bigintegers too.
The error I get from VS10 is :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The questions:

1. Is it possible to accomplish?
2. How can I flag all nodes in number with the use of BigInteger (not int)?
3. Is there an other better method for accomplishing the thing?

**UPDATE**
In the example I use c++ as the counter. This is variable though...
The node list could look like this:

```
numberlist[2]
numberlist[3]
numberlist[200]
numberlist[20034759044900]
numberlist[23847982344986350]
```

I'll remove processed nodes. At the maximum I'll use 1,5gb of memory.
Please reply on this update, I want to know whether my ideas are correct or not.
Also I would like too learn from my mistakes!

Comment: I sincerely doubt that your machine has enough memory to merit an array indexed by a BigInteger. Did I misunderstand your requirements?

Comment: Your question still doesn't make much sense. How can you fit so many nodes into 1.5GB? And what do you do with them? What do you need the index for at all?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I'll have to split it up if it isn't possible to put it into 1,5gb mem. Yet I still need node numbers larger 20 digits.

Comment: A data structure indexed by a signed int can store 2,147,483,648 values. A data structure indexed by a signed long can store 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 values. Do you really need to store more than 2 billion items, let alone more than 9 quintillion items? Perhaps the data is very sparse and you actually want an associative array? Forgetting for a moment how large the "keys" are, how many distinct values do you need to store?

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw: I do not need so many items at the same time, yet if I used a number, processed it and removed it, I do not want to reuse the number simply because a large number isn't supported.

Comment: You're still missing a lot of basic information about what you're doing. Simply counting to 20 digit numbers will take years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your update it seems you don't want to have huge amount of data, you just want to index them using huge numbers. If that's the case, you can use `Dictionary<BigInteger, int>` or `Dictionary<BigInteger, bool>` if you only want `true`/`false` values. Alternatively, you could use `HashSet<BigInteger>`, if you don't need to distinguish between `false` and “not in collection”.

Comment: I'll look the Dictionary<> up. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 5):

The generic argument of `LinkedList<T>` describes the element type and has nothing to do with the number of elements you can put in the collection.

Indexing into a linked list is a bad idea too. It's an O(n) operation.

And I can't imagine how you can have more elements than what fits into an `Int64`. There is simply not enough memory to back that.

You can have more than 2^31-1 elements in a 64bit process, but most likely you need to create your own collection type for that, since most built in collections have lower limits.

If you need more than 2^31 flags I'd create my own collection type that's backed by multiple arrays and bitpacks the flags. That way you get about 8*2^31 = 16 billion flags into a 2GB array.

If your data is sparse you could consider using a `HashSet<Int64>` or `Dictionary<Int64,Node>`.

If your data has long sequences with the same value you could use some tree structure or perhaps some variant of run-length-encoding.

If you don't need the indexes at all, you could just use a `Queue<T>` and dequeue from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

`LinkedList<BigInteger>` is a small number of elements, where each element is a `BigInteger`.

.NET doesn't allow any single array to be larger than 2GB (even on 64-bit), so there's no point in having an index larger than an `int`.

Try breaking your big array into smaller segments, where each segment can be addressed by an `int`.

Comment: But `LinkedList<T>` isn't implemented as a single array, so it *could* have more than 2GB. I'm not saying it's a good idea though.

Comment: @svick: `LinkedList<T>` also doesn't have efficient indexing, so yeah, "not a good idea" is somewhat of an understatement.

Answer (score 2):

If I may read your mind, it sounds like what you want a *sparse array* which is indexed by a `BigInteger`. As others have mentioned, `LinkedList<BigInteger>` is entirely the wrong data structure for this. I suggest something entirely different, namely a `Dictionary<BigInteger, int>`. This allows you to do the following:

```
Dictionary<BigInteger, int> data = new Dictionary<BigInteger, int>();
BigInteger b = GetBigInteger();

data[b] = 1; // the BigInteger is the *index*, and the integer is the *value*
```